# calculating relative focal length based on a cylinder

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d, computer-vision

I am trying to camera match a photo of a cylinder.

The photo is taken relatively straight, and I can get a rotation matrix for the camera based on the elipsis created by projecting the top circle.

[image]

The problem shows up when I try to figure out what focal length the camera has.

My thinking is that given the principal point in the center of the image, and that the x and y axis(green and red) are equal in length in 3d space, I should be able to increase the focal length until they align in length with what is on the screen.

Does this make sense, and is there a mathematical solution to this that I am currently not seeing?

working on the answer by Hosam:
I created an image using [threejs editor](https://threejs.org/editor/).
Placed a cylinder at origo with height 1 and radius 0.5.

Placed the camera arbitrarily at $[0,0.64,1.96]$
Rotated it down(in x) by $-15.4deg$
And lastly set the field of view to $75deg$ (bottom to top)

I then pulled the image into my tool and mapped out all points.
[image: printscr]

from this I got:
$$
a = 0.555 \\
b = 0.039 \\
c_0 = 0.506 \\
$$

I threw this into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F0.555%5E2%3D1%2F0.039%5E2%28-2+sin%280.261%29+cos%280.261%29+%28+0.506%2Fz%29+%2B+cos%280.261%29%5E2%2Bsin%280.261%29%5E2+%280.506%2Fz%29%5E2%29+-+%28sin%280.261%29%5E2%2Fz%5E2%29) as it is a bit quicker than writing the code for it

2 results came out that are quite similar to each other at roughly $0.12$.

so from that focal length I can get a field of view.
$$
2 * atan(1 / 0.12)
$$.
Which problematically does not equal $1.308$ (75deg is radians)

Comment: What is known about the top of the cylinder? Is the elevation of the top known relative to the elevation of the camera?  Is the diameter known ?

Comment: Do you mind adding the details concerning how exactly you obtain the rotation matrix for the camera based on the ellipse?

Comment: the diameter is known.
the inputs I have is the image and a user who has pointed out a straight line in the x axis that is equal in length to the diameter of the cylinder.
additionally the user points out the y axis and where that meets the edge of the ellipse.

then given the diameter in x and the radius in y, I can assume that they should be equal in length and the z should be the crossproduct of the two. And that I think gives me the rotation matrix

Comment: Assuming the top of the cylinder is horizontal, you have to know the angle of depression of the camera axis (with respect to the horizontal plane) to be able to find the focal length.

Comment: hmm, do I really need to know it? I understand that it relates to the focal length, but that relationship will also get constrained by the height of the cylinder and how the bottom gets projected onto the screen(assuming that a user points out where the cylinder hits the ground plane).

Comment: The formula for the field of view (FOV) is  $$\alpha = 2 \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{S}{2f} \right) $$  where $S$ is the **diagonal size of the sensor**.  Is there a way to find the value of $S$.  Also your calculation for the focal length is incorrect.  $\theta $ whose $\sin$ and $\cos$ are used in the formula satisfies $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \phi $, where $\phi = \left(\dfrac{\pi}{180}\right) \times 15.4 $.  The values for the focal length that I got were $2.518$ and $1.432$.  My experimentation indicates that we should pick the larger value, i.e. $2.518$.  You need to get the value of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your identified ellipse (which lies in the image plane) is given by the $2D$ curve

$ p(t) = C + \cos t u_1 + \sin t u_2 $

where $C$ is the center of the ellipse, $u_1, u_2$ are the semi-axes of the ellipse.  Since the photo is taken straight, then we can assume that

$ C = (0, c_0) $

$ u_1 = (a, 0 ) $

$ u_2 = (0, b) $

where $c_0, a$ and $b$ are known.

Since the image plane lies a distance $z_0$ from the center of the camera (the origin of the camera coordinate frame), then with respect to the camera coordinate frame, the equation of the ellipse is

$ p(t) = (0, c_0, -z_0) + \cos t (a, 0, 0) + \sin t (0, b, 0) $

Connecting the origin to the points of this ellipse generates a **cone** of view.

It can be shown that this cone has the equation

$p^T Q p = 0 $

where

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{a^2} && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && \dfrac{1}{b^2} && \dfrac{c_0}{b^2 z_0} \\ 0 && \dfrac{c_0}{b^2 z_0} && \dfrac{ c^2 }{(b z_0)^2} - \dfrac{1}{z_0^2} \end{bmatrix} $

This cone of view is to be **intersected** with a plane representing the top of the cylinder which is assumed horizontal in the world coordinate frame.  Now, with respect to the camera coordinate frame, the equation of this "horizontal" plane is

$ n^T p = K $

where $K$ is an arbitrary non-zero constant. And

$ n = [0, \sin \theta, \cos \theta ]^T =:[0, s, c ]^T $

It can be shown that this intersection curve between the cone of view and the plane representing the top of the cylinder will be a circle if and only if

$ \dfrac{1}{a^2} = \dfrac{1}{b^2} \left( - 2 s c \dfrac{c_0}{z_0} + c^2 + s^2 \left( \dfrac{c_0}{z_0} \right)^2 \right) - \dfrac{s^2}{z_0^2} $

This equation relates the angle $\theta$ (which is the angle between the camera axis (it's $z$ axis) and the normal of the intercepting plane of the cylinder top.

Since the plane of the cylinder top is horizontal, then the camera must be pointing in a direction that makes an angle of $\phi =\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta \ $ **below** the horizontal.

The above equation implies that to determine the focal length $z_0$ we need to know the angle $\phi$ at which the camera was pointing.  Then solving for $z_0$ is a a matter of solving a quadratic equation in $\left( \dfrac{1}{z_0} \right) $, which is trivial.

[image]

Comment: I will be honest and say that my math skills aren't excelent(if not already obvious). But let's see if I got this right: to begin with I will assume that my camera rotation is correct. So I begin with taking the cameras direction(it's z axis), and compare that to the camera direction with world y=0, giving me phi. from there theta is given, and thus s and c is given by sin/cos of theta. a is the width of the elipsis / 2, to get the radius. b is the same but for height. And then I should be able to solve the equation assuming c0 = 1.... did I understand that correctly?

Comment: You got it.  However $c_0$ is not $1$.  It is equal to the y-coordinate of the center of the ellipse, which is known.

Comment: I am getting nowhere close to the right answer... I happen to know that in my reference image I need a relative focal distance of 7 (relative to normalized device coordinates), and I am getting values in the range of 1+-0.3. That said I feel like your answer makes sense, and it is likely an implementation error somewhere on my part

Comment: Yes.  I believe so too.  Because I've tested the equation on a perspective image of a circle, that I generated.  From the generated image, I calculated $c_0, a, b$.  I also know the set value of $\phi$.  Using this I correctly calculated the focal length, which turned out to be equal to the set value that I started with to generate the image of the circle.

Comment: I updated my question with an example. Does anything stick out as wildly off to you?

Comment: I am not familiar with the field of view angle.  Isn't this for cameras with lenses ?

Comment: The field of view is given by $$ \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{H}{2f} \right) $$ where $H$ is the height of the film and $f$ is the focal length.  Your calculation of the focal length is incorrect because $\theta = 90^\circ - 15.4^\circ = 74.6^\circ = 1.302015 $.  I've calculated the focal length from the quadratic equation that I derived in my solution, and got two possible values $2.518$ and $1.432$.  Pick the larger value.  Now from the image you provided, we have $H \approx 2.5 $.  This a $FOV = 2 \tan^{-1}\left( \dfrac{2.5}{5.036} \right) = 52.8^\circ \ne 75^\circ$